# Erlang: Distributed Application Strange behaviour

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I'm paying with distributed erlang applications.

Configuration and ideas are taken from:
http:/www.erlang.org/doc/pdf/otp-system-documentation.pdf **9.9. Distributed Applications**

- We have 3 nodes: n1@a2-X201, n2@a2-X201, n3@a2-X201
- We have application **wd** that do some useful job :)

Configuration files:

- wd1.config - for the first node:

```
      [{kernel,
          [{distributed,[{wd,5000,['n1@a2-X201',{'n2@a2-X201','n3@a2-X201'}]}]},
           {sync_nodes_mandatory,['n2@a2-X201','n3@a2-X201']},
           {sync_nodes_timeout,5000}
        ]}
      ,{sasl, [
      %% All reports go to this file
      {sasl_error_logger,{file,"/tmp/wd_n1.log"}}
      ]
    }].
```

- wd2.config for the second:

```
    [{kernel,
        [{distributed,[{wd,5000,['n1@a2-X201',{'n2@a2-X201','n3@a2-X201'}]}]},
         {sync_nodes_mandatory,['n1@a2-X201','n3@a2-X201']},
         {sync_nodes_timeout,5000}
         ]
     }
    ,{sasl, [
        %% All reports go to this file
        {sasl_error_logger,{file,"/tmp/wd_n2.log"}}
    ]
    }].
```

- For the node n3 looks similar.

Now start erlang in 3 separate terminals:

- erl  -sname n1@a2-X201 -config wd1 -pa $WD_EBIN_PATH -boot start_sasl
- erl  -sname n2@a2-X201 -config wd2 -pa $WD_EBIN_PATH -boot start_sasl
- erl  -sname n3@a2-X201 -config wd3 -pa $WD_EBIN_PATH -boot start_sasl

Start application on each of erlang nodes:
* application:start(wd).

```
(n1@a2-X201)1> application:start(wd).

=INFO REPORT==== 19-Jun-2011::15:42:51 ===
wd_plug_server starting... PluginId: 4 Path: "/home/a2/src/erl/data/SIG" FileMask: "(?i)(.*)\\.SIG$" 
ok
```

```
(n2@a2-X201)1> application:start(wd).
ok
(n2@a2-X201)2>
```

```
(n3@a2-X201)1> application:start(wd).
ok
(n3@a2-X201)2>
```

At the moment everything is Ok. As written in Erlang documentation: Application is running at node **n1@a2-X201**

Now kill node **n1**: 
Application was migrated to **n2**

```
(n2@a2-X201)2> 
=INFO REPORT==== 19-Jun-2011::15:46:28 ===
wd_plug_server starting... PluginId: 4 Path: "/home/a2/src/erl/data/SIG" FileMask: "(?i)(.*)\\.SIG$"
```

Continue our game: kill node **n2**
One more time system works fine. We have our application at node **n3**

```
(n3@a2-X201)2> 
=INFO REPORT==== 19-Jun-2011::15:48:18 ===
wd_plug_server starting... PluginId: 4 Path: "/home/a2/src/erl/data/SIG" FileMask: "(?i)(.*)\\.SIG$"
```

Now restore nodes **n1** and **n2**. 
So:

```
Erlang R14B (erts-5.8.1) [source] [smp:4:4] [rq:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.8.1  (abort with ^G)
(n1@a2-X201)1> 

Eshell V5.8.1  (abort with ^G)
(n2@a2-X201)1>
```

Nodes **n1**  and **n2** are back.
Looks like now I have to restart application manually:
*  Let's do it at node **n2** first:

```
(n2@a2-X201)1> application:start(wd).
```

- Looks like it hanged ...
- Now restart it at **n1**

```
(n1@a2-X201)1> application:start(wd).

=INFO REPORT==== 19-Jun-2011::15:55:43 ===
wd_plug_server starting... PluginId: 4 Path: "/home/a2/src/erl/data/SIG" FileMask: "(?i)(.*)\\.SIG$" 

ok
(n1@a2-X201)2>
```

It works. And node **n2** also has returned OK:

```
Eshell V5.8.1  (abort with ^G)
(n2@a2-X201)1> application:start(wd).
ok
(n2@a2-X201)2>
```

At node **n3** we see:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 19-Jun-2011::15:55:43 ===
    application: wd
    exited: stopped
    type: temporary
```

In general, everything looks ok, as written in documentation, except for delay with starting application at node **n2**.

Now kill node **n1** once more:

```
(n1@a2-X201)2> 
User switch command
 --> q
[a2@a2-X201 releases]$
```

Ops ... everything hangs. Application was not restarted at another node.

Actually, while I was writing this post I've realized that sometime everything id Ok, sometime I have a problem.

Any ideas, While there could be problems when restoring "primary" node nd killing it one more time?

Comment: Nice question: A lot of votes but no answers :)

Answer (score 1):

As [explained over at Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/distributed-otp-applications) (scroll to the bottom), distributed applications only work well when started as part of a release, not when you start them manually with `application:start`.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the oddity you're seeing is likely to do with you restarting your application entirely on nodes n1/n2 while n3 is still running under the initial application initialisation.

If your application starts any system-wide processes and uses their pids rather than using registered names set with global, pg or pg2 for example, then you may be working with two sets of global state.

If this is the case, the recommended approach to take is to focus on adding/removing nodes from an existing application rather than restarting an application in it's entirety. This way nodes are leaving and joining into an existing set of initialised values.

Comment: Actually, I do not use PID's, I use registered names. There are gen_server implementation behavior that I register using {local,Name}. So, it seams to me that this should not be a problem. I do not fully understand how could i add/remove nodes from the running application? Do you have any code examples? Thanks